# FIREBASE WARNING: set at /notifications/ failed: permission_denied

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-security

I followed the instructions as per tutorial [here](https://github.com/ireade/simply-notify).  The only difference is that I separated the Subscribe and Sending of notifications into 2 different pages.  Here is the [Subscribe Page](https://notes-pushies.firebaseapp.com/) and here is the [Dashboard](https://notes-pushies.firebaseapp.com/pages/dashboard/).

The issue is after the user has subscribed successfully and I try to push a notification in the Dashboard, I get an error

```
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /notifications/-L6ZAsl77V-patpjL8vT failed: permission_denied
```

But comparing it with the [tutorial/demo](https://simply-notify.firebaseapp.com/), there is no error and the message is pushed through the end user.

Any ideas?

The database security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "tokens": {
        ".indexOn": ["uid", "token"],
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
        "$token": {
            ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['uid', 'token']) && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid"
        }
    },
    "notifications": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
        "$notification": {
            ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['user', 'message', 'userProfileImg'])"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a firebase rule issue. IIRC, everything is write-disabled by default, so you'll need to set the rule to allow this yourself. Can you show us what your firebase rules look like for the `notifications` node?

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    "tokens": {
      ".indexOn": [
        "uid",
        "token"
      ],
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "$token": {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['uid', 'token']) && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "notifications": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "$notification": {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['user', 'message', 'userProfileImg'])"
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: @CRice, its just weird that the code is as per the tutorial and her demo works like a charm

Comment: This error message has nothing to do with Cloud Messaging and everything with your Firebase database and its security rules. Please **edit** your question (there's a link right under it) to include the write operation that triggers the error/warning message.

Comment: OK, looks legit (and it's the same as in the linked repo), so rules aren't the issue. Could be that the user attempting the write isn't authenticated (I feel like it's probably this), or that the data they're trying to set doesn't have those required fields. Can you show us the code that attempts the write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake.  I assumed that it was a 1:1 between demo and my own.

In one of my JS files where its suppose to call `/notifications`, I removed `user` and `userProfileImg` without updating the rules in `database.rule.json`.  It still read:

```
 "$notification": {
      ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['user', 'message', 'userProfileImg'])"
 }
```

When I removed the `'user'` and `'userProfileImg'` from the json file, everything worked again.